# deja-dup back up fail unknown error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Using Ubuntu 14.04 for a short time. Back up started failing and returning this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1337, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1370, in do_backup
    globals.archive_dir).set_values()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 697, in set_values
    self.get_backup_chains(partials + backend_filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 819, in get_backup_chains
    map(add_to_sets, filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 809, in add_to_sets
    if set.add_filename(filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 100, in add_filename
    (self.volume_name_dict, filename)
AssertionError: ({1: 'duplicity-inc.20140615T154649Z.to.20140616T205256Z.vol1.difftar.gz', 2: 'duplicity-inc.20140615T154649Z.to.20140616T205256Z.vol2.difftar.gz', 3: 'duplicity-inc.20140615T154649Z.to.20140616T205256Z.vol3.difftar'}, 'duplicity-inc.20140615T154649Z.to.20140616T205256Z.vol3.difftar.gz')
```

advice please?